# sbt.ResolveException unresolved dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to work on Twitter stream sample project. i am facing problem while defining sbt.

my build.sbt

```
name := "Tutorial"
version := "0.1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
retrieveManaged := true
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "2.11.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.1.0"
)
```

Error Log:

```
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.9.2 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.11.8)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:2.2.0 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.11.8)
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.5.1 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.11.8)
[warn] 
[error] {file:/home/muralee1857/scala/workspace/Tutorial/}default-109f4d/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11.8;1.5.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.9.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.5.1: not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to define explicitly the packaged versions to the dependency as

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.1.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.10" % "1.1.0"
)
```

You can use `%%` without defining the `packaged version` but that will try to download the `package with scala version` in your system. And sometimes `sbt` will not find the `scala version packaged packages` which will create dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. note that I am using `%%` method instead of `%` here so that right version of the spark library (scala version 2.11) is selected here. ensure you apply the same `%%` function to others plugins like sbt-assembly, sbt-assembly etc.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.11.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.1.0"
)
```

Comment: My issue got resolved, i have changed my scala compiler to 2.10 after that compatibility issue got resoled with external jars.